# How to recive and parse a HTTP Json-File in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, http, parsing, kotlin

I´m programming an Android App that recives Data from an other device (not jet final what device some kind of Wifi board) via HTTP Json-File but i dont know how to "pull" the file and parse it. I´m new to Kotlin so thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your not just new to android. You will need a webhost server set up. The easiest way would set it up so that when the url is connect to it echos your json response. When your app executes its http get request you parse the resonse.

I highly recommend Fuel for kotlin. It just works. 
[Kittinunf/fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel)